# emacs org-protocol invocation through javascript bookmarklet in chrome

Tags: javascript, bash, emacs, bookmarklet, org-mode

**Setup**

Cygwin Emacs, and I have a *partially* working setup with `org-protocol`.  Org-protocol is a way to capture information from the browser and pass it to Emacs.  I used a Windows 7 registry modification to add `org-protocol` to the list of known protocols and, to enable cygwin's `bash` to startup `emacsclient` to handle those requests.  Partially working meaning that bookmarklet and emacs loading operations are successful except for the problem case below.

**Problem**

I select interesting text on the page, and invoke the bookmarklet, but some characters are not correctly escaped by using `encodeURIComponent` alone (namely, parentheses and the single quote).  This wreaks havoc causing parse errors for bash.  I don't know of a way to handle this potential quoting problem with bash alone, so I thought to modify the bookmarklet, to replace any problematic characters.

The code below **works** when invoked inside Chrome's JS console, but **NOT** when invoked as a bookmarklet.  I also tried redo'ing it with `(function(){...})()` syntax with the same, failed result.

What solutions ( bash, bookmarklet, other? ) do I have?

**Bookmarklet Code**

```
javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture://'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection()).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/\(/g,"%28").replace(/\)/g,"%29")
```

**Registry Mod**

Also, here is the command line invocation - in case there is some problem with my quoting scheme.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol]
@="URL:Org Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol\shell\open\command]
@="\"cmd.exe\" \"/k\" \"C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe\" \"--login\" \"-c\" \"DISPLAY=:0 /usr/local/bin/emacsclient -c %1\""
```

Comment: When you say it does not work, does it do nothing at all or not what you expect ?

Comment: @tomdemuyt: when I say does not work, I mean the punctuation causes bash parse errors.  so the highlighted text is not correctly used in the invocation of emacs.